# Oracle not allowing large fields for common users after setting max_string_size=EXTENDED

Tags: oracle

I'm using an Oracle 19.3 enterprise Docker container and enabling `max_string_size=EXTENDED`. When creating a table with a large field using the `sys` user, Oracle allows the table to be created. But when attempting to create a table with a large field using a common user, Oracle acts as if extended mode has not been enabled. Here are the reproduction steps:

1. Navigate to the [Oracle Container Registry](https://container-registry.oracle.com/).
2. Click on "Database", then “enterprise“.
3. Accept the license terms on the right side top. Sign-in is required.
4. Ensure that Docker Desktop is installed and running on your local machine.
5. In a command prompt, run the shell commands below to login, download, and run the docker image:

```
docker login -u <email> -p <password> container-registry.oracle.com
docker run -d -it --name oracle-19-db -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PWD=Oradoc_db1 container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.3.0.0
```

6. Wait a few minutes for the Oracle database to startup - check the logs in Docker Desktop to view progress.
7. Open a terminal window to the Docker container using the Docker Desktop icon.
8. Run `export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB`
9. Run `sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1 as sysdba`
10. Within `sqlplus`, run the following commands:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
STARTUP UPGRADE
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_string_size=EXTENDED scope=spfile;
START $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utl32k.sql
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
STARTUP
```

11. Within `sqlplus`, verify that extended mode is working:

```
SHOW PARAMETER max_string_size
CREATE TABLE char_test(c1 varchar2(32767));
```

12. Within `sqlplus`, create the common user:

```
CREATE USER C##COMMERCEDB PROFILE DEFAULT IDENTIFIED BY mypassword
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

GRANT CONNECT, CREATE TABLE, CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE PROCEDURE TO C##COMMERCEDB;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_XA TO C##COMMERCEDB;
GRANT SELECT ON PENDING_TRANS$ TO C##COMMERCEDB;
GRANT SELECT ON DBA_2PC_PENDING TO C##COMMERCEDB;
GRANT SELECT ON DBA_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS TO C##COMMERCEDB;
```

13. Exit `sqlplus` and reconnect as the common user:

```
quit
sqlplus C##COMMERCEDB/mypassword
```

14. Within `sqlplus`, attempt to create a table with a large field:

```
CREATE TABLE char_test(c1 varchar2(32767));
```

The error occurs:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a container database. That is not how you enable Extended Datatypes in a CDB.

[MAX_STRING_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html)

I will not copy and format the steps here due to their length, just follow this section:

**Increasing the Maximum Size of VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, and RAW Columns in a CDB**

And you should work and create objects in a pluggable database, not the root container, that goes against the concept.

Update:

The above documentation specifically mentions this will not work in CDB root:

> **Note:** The root continues to use STANDARD semantics even after MAX_STRING_SIZE is set to EXTENDED. The reason for setting
> MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED in the root is so all the PDBs in the CDB
> can inherit the EXTENDED setting from the root.

Here my output of making it work:

https://pastebin.com/UaMQJtJL

Comment: Thanks Balazs, I just tried following the steps described in that article, however, I'm still getting the same error when running the `CREATE TABLE` command as the common user.

Comment: @Templar Did you connect to a pluggable database to create the table? The above documentation specifically mentions this: `Note:The root continues to use STANDARD semantics even after MAX_STRING_SIZE is set to EXTENDED. The reason for setting MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED in the root is so all the PDBs in the CDB can inherit the EXTENDED setting from the root.`

Comment: @Templar See my update in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! As you said, the trick was to connect to the PDB using `sqlplus C##COMMERCEDB/mypassword@localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1` instead of just `sqlplus C##COMMERCEDB/mypassword`.